# correct way to parse a list of params in a url

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

What is the correct way to pass a lit of values via url parameters.

For instance I am trying to pass something like this

```
/sports?country=USA&play=['nba','nfl']
```

In my aws lambda which is in node.js when i do the following
`var playList = event.queryStringParameters.play` I get back `['nba','nfl']` but it is a string and not a list

Then I tried the following

```
/sports?country=USA&play=nba,nfl
```

In my aws lambda I did `event.queryStringParameters.play.split(',')` and i got a list `[nba,nfl]` but this is a issue when there is only 1 item passed like /sports?country=USA&play=nba because then i cannot split on ,

Hence i am wondering what is the correct way to pass a list as i feel there maybe a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with using `/sports?country=USA&play=nba,nfl` and then doing `split` to get the values. It can handler multiple or single values just fine

```js
console.log("nba,nfl".split(',')); // will result in [nba,nfl]
```

```js
console.log("nba".split(',')); // will result in [nba]
```

Comment: You are correct there is not issue with it actually